# Javascript/Jquery sum input fields as user enters

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to be blunt; I am weak with Javascript/Jquery. I am learning :) I am very strong in PHP.

I have a table that shows a user a single line item that they can enter information into. This form is a "change order". I am having difficulties understanding what I need to do to get the input fields "Count" and "Price" to sum by the example in the Total Category. I would also need to have this summation occur during each new row inserted.

This page will generate a template'd PDF document containing the line items entered.

[image]

My Javascript code ive put together is;

```
    let count = 0;
    $('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
        count += 1;
    })
    $('#myTable').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
    })
    $('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
        var varItem = 'item_' + count;
        var varCount = 'count_' + count;
        var varPrice = 'price_' + count;
        var varTotal = 'total_' + count;
        $('#myTable').append('' +
            '<tr>' +
                '<td>' +
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="' + varItem + '"/>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="' + varCount + '"/>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="' + varPrice + '"/>' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    'Count * Price = Total' +
                '</td>' +
                '<td>' +
                    '<input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete" />' +
                '</td>' +
            '</tr>'
        )
    });
```

HTML

```
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-striped width-full">
                                    <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th>Item</th>
                                        <th>Count</th>
                                        <th>Price</th>
                                        <th>Total</th>
                                        <th>Action</th>
                                    </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_0" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="count_0" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price_0" />
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                Count * Price = Total
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
```

Comment: You have `jQuery` code and not `javascript`.

Comment: if you are strong in php, just ommit the `;` and the `$` and you are strong in js too :P

Comment: I can't see` input button` within `p` tag ` $('p input[type="button"]')`. You want total to be displayed as new row is created? I am not really clear about the question. But, when new row is added the price and count input fields are empty.

Comment: @johnSmith I am learning that; few things throw me for a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this [codepen](https://codepen.io/chin-ngh/pen/pmqYKV) base on your code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  let count = 0;
  $('p input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    count += 1;
  })
  $('#myTable').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function() {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  })
  $('p input[type="button"]').click(function() {
    var varItem = 'item_' + count;
    var varCount = 'count_' + count;
    var varPrice = 'price_' + count;
    var varTotal = 'total_' + count;
    $('#myTable').append('' +
      '<tr>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="' + varItem + '"/>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control quantity" name="' + varCount + '"/>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<input type="text" class="form-control price" name="' + varPrice + '"/>' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td class="' + varTotal + '">' +
      'Count * Price = Total' +
      '</td>' +
      '<td>' +
      '<input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete" />' +
      '</td>' +
      '</tr>'
    )
  });

  $(document).on("change", ".quantity", function() {
    $quantity = $(this);
    $index = $quantity.attr('name').split('_')[1]
    $price = $('input[name="price_' + $index + '"]').val()
    $('.total_' + $index).text($price ? $price * $quantity.val() : 0)
    // alert($price);  // jQuery 1.7+
  });

  $(document).on("change", ".price", function() {
    $price = $(this);
    $index = $price.attr('name').split('_')[1]
    $quantity = $('input[name="count_' + $index + '"]').val()
    $('.total_' + $index).text($quantity ? $quantity * $price.val() : 0)
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p><input type='button' value='Add'></p>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-striped width-full">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Count</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

The idea is to bind the event to `quantity` & `price` input fields whenever their values change, then update the total value at corresponding row index. In order to bind change events for dynamically added elements, please refer to [JQuery's live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) helper.

You will then see the cart working as following image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Add a class name to your price inputs (ive added priceInput)

`<input type="text" class="form-control priceInput" name="' + varPrice + '"/>`

then find the sum with

```
sum = 0
$( ".printInput" ).each(function( index ) {
  sum+= Number($( this ).val())
});
console.log("The sum is : " + sum)
```

Comment: Doesn't `$( this ).val()` return a string in this case? So your sum will be a string?

Comment: Not sure if it does this, but I've added parseInt just incase. Thanks :)

Comment: Reflected the above. Smart Man.

Answer (score 0):

Apply the `change` event to `price` and `count` input. When both the values are present, change the `text` of `total` field with the val of `price*count`.

```js
let count = 0;

$('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    count += 1;
})
$('#myTable').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function () {
    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
})
$('p input[type="button"]').click(function () {
    var varItem = 'item_' + count;
    var varCount = 'count_' + count;
    var varPrice = 'price_' + count;
    var varTotal = 'total_' + count;
    $('#myTable').append('' +
        '<tr>' +
            '<td>' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="' + varItem + '"/>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="' + varCount + '"/>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
                '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="' + varPrice + '"/>' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
                'Count * Price = Total' +
            '</td>' +
            '<td>' +
                '<input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete" />' +
            '</td>' +
        '</tr>'
    );
    calculateTotal();
});

function calculateTotal() {
    $('input[name^="count"], input[name^="price"]').on('change', function() {
        const inputName = $(this).attr('name').split('_')[1];
        const count = +($(`input[name="count_${inputName}"]`).val());
        const price = +($(`input[name="price_${inputName}"]`).val());

        if(count && price) {
            const total = $(`input[name="price_${inputName}"]`).parent().next();
            $(total).text(count*price);
        }
    });
}

calculateTotal();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable" class="table table-hover table-striped width-full">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Count</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="item_0" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="count_0" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="price_0" />
      </td>
      <td>
        Count * Price = Total
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" value="Delete" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<p>
  <input type="button" value="Add Row">
</p>
```